# How to use one form to insert two entities in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, entities, persist

I've found a technique to insert data in two entities with one form here:

http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=42011

My problem is that `getData()` return an array of objects and I can't use it with the `persist()` method because it expects an object. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
$data = $form->getData();
foreach ($data as $object) {
    $em->persist($object);
}
$em->flush();
```